# Handoff feature devices requirement

Tags: iphone, ipad, mac, macos, ios

Why are supported devices for Handoff feature so strict to a small set of devices?

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6555

Answer (score 1):

Handoff requires three things:

- specific bluetooth hardware - this eliminates most of the older devices
- specific wireless hardware - this has to do with MIMO antennas and a sophisticated wireless chip. This doesn't eliminate many devices as bluetooth capabilities were upgraded at the same time as wifi as far as I can tell.
- a fast enough CPU

Thus the list of devices that support handoff is related directly to new hardware capabilities.